# NSView alpha on viewDidLoad doesn't display

Tags: swift, nsview

I have a custom NSView which I set the isEnabled flag in viewDidLoad but it is not displaying at 0.5 alpha, even though isEnabled is correctly set and the correct code is called in drawRect for the custom view.

As soon as I click a text field in the same view controller the view alpha changes.

Here is the code called in viewDidLoad

```
        forceOutput.isEnabled = true
```

And here is the code called by drawRect

```
        // is the view enabled?
    if isEnabled {

        // alpha should be full (opaque)
        self.alphaValue = 1.0

    } else {

        // make the view slightly transparent
        self.alphaValue = 0.5
    }
```

Comment: You sir are a star, thank you. I already had a `didSet` which was setting `needsDisplay`, so I've just changed that and it works perfectly. Hadn't realised that alpha wouldn't be handled properly at `drawRect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting alpha in `drawRect` is generally too late in the rendering process. If setting alpha, do it before `drawRect` is called. Perhaps set the alpha in `viewDidLoad`. Or, better, have a `didSet` for the `isEnabled` property that sets the alpha. But don't do it in `drawRect`, itself.